# Having trouble applying stamens toner style to SQLite lines layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I am an absolute QGIS/GIS beginner using 3.22 QGIS software.

My goal is to load a sector of the United States with the stamens toner lite style.

I downloaded my data from [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html).

I then used ogr2ogr to convert the pbf file to a SQLite database

I can navigate to the DB and load the lines and have them render on my project just fine.

The problem is when I go to Properties>styles and apply the toner-lite style [from](https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/tree/master/qgis2/osm_spatialite)

Nothing seems to happen.

At first I thought maybe it takes longer to render, but even after it seems to do it's rendering the roads never showed up.

It renders the multipolygons fine, but the roads never show up.

I experimented on a smaller data set in the experiment presented by anita at this [link](https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/), and loading the styles worked there without problems.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By seemingly dumb luck I figured out the problem. For anyone else who is struggling with this in the future: changing the reference system to `EPSG:3785` solved the problem (perhaps others may work, or likely the one I had selected was not adequate.)

Comment: Do you mean EPSG:3857?